# line output from a text file which matches a search string (simplify program code)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to simplify the following program code which actually works. The intention is to search for a string to be specified in a text file (log file) and output these lines but also 5 lines prior and behind this line. If in the 5 lines behind the matching line the search string occurs again it must be avoided that the lines will be displayed or exported more than once. Any tips are much appreciated.

```
def analyze(search_string, outdev):
    file = "infile.txt"
    print "investigating file: " + file + " ..."
    line1 = ""
    line2 = ""
    line3 = ""
    line4 = ""
    line5 = ""
    line6 = ""
    n = 0
    output = 0

    if outdev == "s":               ### output: screen
        data = open(file, "r")
        for line in data.readlines():
            line6 = line5
            line5 = line4
            line4 = line3
            line3 = line2
            line2 = line1
            line1 = line
            if line.find(search_string) != -1 and output == 0:
                output = 1
                print ""
                print "-" * 80
                print ""
                print line6
                print line5
                print line4
                print line3
                print line2
                print ""
                print "." * 20
                print ""
                n = 1
                changed = 1
                found = 1
            if output == 1 and 1 <= n <= 6 :
                if line.find(search_string) != -1:
                    if found == 0:
                        changed = 1
                    else:
                        changed = 0
                    found = 1
                else:
                    if found == 1:
                        changed = 1
                    else:
                        changed = 0
                    found = 0
                if changed == 1:
                    print ""
                    print "." * 20
                    print ""
                    changed = 0
                print line
                n += 1
                if line.find(search_string) != -1:
                    n = 1
                if n == 6:
                    n = 0
                    output = 0
        data.close()

    if outdev == "f":               ### output: file
        out_file = "outfile.txt"
        out_f = open(out_file, "w")
        data = open(file, "r")
        for line in data.readlines():
            line6 = line5
            line5 = line4
            line4 = line3
            line3 = line2
            line2 = line1
            line1 = line
            if line.find(search_string) != -1 and output == 0:
                output = 1
                out_f.write(lf + "-" * 128 + lf + lf)
                out_f.write(line6)
                out_f.write(line5)
                out_f.write(line4)
                out_f.write(line3)
                out_f.write(line2)
                out_f.write(lf + "." * 20 + lf + lf)
                n = 1
                changed = 1
                found = 1
            if output == 1 and 1 <= n <= 6 :
                if line.find(search_string) != -1:
                    if found == 0:
                        changed = 1
                    else:
                        changed = 0
                    found = 1
                else:
                    if found == 1:
                        changed = 1
                    else:
                        changed = 0
                    found = 0
                if changed == 1:
                    out_f.write(lf + "." * 20 + lf + lf)
                    changed = 0
                out_f.write(line)                   # output recent line
                n += 1                              # increase counter
                if line.find(search_string) != -1:  # Search String found : reset counter
                    n = 1
                if n == 6:
                    n = 0
                    output = 0
        data.close()
        out_f.close()
```

...
As asked by  inspectorG4dget :
"changed" is a flag to store the state of the previous line in order to control the the output of the interlines ("." * 20).
Please find the comments to see is how it works:

```
            if line.find(search_string) != -1:  ## does the recent line contain the search string:
                                ##  => Yes:
                if found == 0:          ##      was there a match in the previous line?
                    changed = 1     ##      => No: the state has changed
                else:           
                    changed = 0     ##      => Yes: the state didn't change
                found = 1           ##      store the state of the recent line in the found-flag 
            else:                   ##  => No:
                if found == 1:          ##      was there a match in the previous line?
                    changed = 1     ##      => Yes: the state has changed
                else:
                    changed = 0     ##      => No: the state didn't change
                found = 0           ##      store the state of the recent line in the found-flag
```

Comment: What's the deal with `changed`? Also, you could skip the `'s'` and `'f'` output switches, and do `python myscript.py > file_name` if you want to output to a file

Comment: I have extended my original question to answer your question concerning the "changed" flag

Comment: Ive got a headache, hope you find an answer tho

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about improving working code. It is more suitable for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is what I would do:

```
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.buffer = []
        self.size = size
    def add(self, elem):
        if len(self.buffer) == self.size:
            self.buffer.pop(0)
        self.buffer.append(elem)
    def getElems(self):
        for elem in self.buffer:
            yield elem

def analyze(search_string):
    buffer = Buffer(5)
    with open("infile.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip()
            if search_string in line:
                if any(search_string in l for l in buffer): continue
                print '-'*80
                for e in buffer.getElems(): print e
                print '.'*20
                print line

            buffer.add(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": analyze("search_string")
```

Once you have this, then you can decide where to send the output like this:

Send it to the screen:

```
$ python my_script.py
```

Send it to a file:

```
$ python my_script.py > some_file.txt
```